# Nginx location regex issue

Tags: regex, nginx, location

Trying to get my nginx location regex to trigger whether the ending "/" is present or not.

So far it only fires when not present. Please help

```
     location ~ ^/page\-[0-9]*$ {
            root /sites/gibranali;
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?pagination=$1 last;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

figured it out. here's the answer for posterity

```
location ~ ^/page\-[0-9]/?$ {
```

Comment: This regex will allow you `/page-1` to `/page-9` (with optionnal trailling `/` ), if you need any number after `/page-` the correct regex is : `^/page\-[0-9]*/?$`